# ¿Cómo leer la respuesta del servidor sin usar AJAX en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, internet-explorer, struts, response

Entorno: Java 4, Struts 1, IE7.

Quiero leer el contenido de la respuesta que me llega del servidor, el cual es una string en formato json y mostrarlo en una nueva ventana.

Aunque funcione:

- **edit1:** No quiero hacerlo con ajax porque no quiero hacer 2 peticiones al servidor pudiendo hacer una. Es justo lo que quiero evitar, ya que la información que necesito ya la tengo en la response. Además porque es información que se va a mostrar 1 vez. Ajax es para páginas dinamicas, cuya información puede cambiar a interacción del usuario.
- No quiero hacerlo seteando atributos en la request porque para eso está la response.
- No quiero hacerlo mediante un formulario porque el formulario no se corresponde con la página que estoy mostrando y porque tampoco hay ningun submit que hacer.
- No puedo usar funciones como fetch() porque no está disponible en IE7.

El proceso que sigue el programa es:
El usuario pulsa un botón que hace una llamada a un metodo del servidor->Este redirecciona a una nueva ventana, escribiendo en la response la información solicitada.

Todos los ejemplos que encuentro en internet involucran a la request, pero **ya tengo el contenido en la response, no quiero realizar otra request.**

Además, ajax lee la respuesta a la request que hace de alguna manera..¿Cómo lo hace?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    var data = //leer response de alguna manera;
    alert("Respuesta:"+data);

});
</script>
```

Comment: No entiendo porque no quieres hacerlo con Ajax, pero de todos modos quiero hacerte saber que ajax tiene un atributo que es async y puedes decirle que sea false. async: false.

Comment: @IñigoIrigoyenErquicia - Editado. El atributo async no va a evitar que ajax haga otra request.

Comment: Pues no se entiende tu pregunta. Si ya tienes los datos para que quieres obtenerlos? El response en que lenguaje esta? Cómo lo obtienes?

Answer (score 1):

Cuando el servidor responde a la solicitud, puede usar objetos predefinidos para recuperar información de dicha respuesta. Por lo tanto podría recuperar un dato y asignarlo directamente en JavaScript:

**Codigo Java en una pagina JSP:**

```
<%
String cadenaJson = response.getAttribute("jsonResponse");
%>
```

**Código javascript en el cual se incrusta el valor de la variable anterior:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    var data = "<%=cadenaJson%>";
    alert("Respuesta:"+data);

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

como comento Iñigo, gracias al atributo `async` podes hacer una llamada ajax en modalidad sincrona. 
en todo caso con javascript podrias hacer una llamada HTTP :

```
  const Http = new HMLHttpRequest();
  const Url = "(url del servidor)";
  Http.open("GET", url); //podes usar post tambien 
  Http.send();
```

utilizar la respuesta respuesta  :

```
 Http.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
       console.log(Http.responseText);
    }
 }
```

**EDIT**

para pasar unicamente la string podes hacer asi :

```
 newWin = window.open("");
 newWin.document.write(response);
```

lo que hace el pedazo de codigo es abrir una nueva ventana (blanca) y escribir lo que le pases ya sea una variable o una string u otra cosa.

Estpero que te sea de ayuda

Comment: Como ya escribi en la descripción de la pregunta: "ya tengo el contenido en la response, no quiero realizar otra request."

Comment: podes utilizar los cookies entonces para almacenar los datos

Comment: Las cookies se utilizan para guardar datos y preferencias de usuario. Pone por ejemplo que quiero recuperar todas las características de un auto pulsando un botón. No voy a poner eso en cookies.

Comment: el problema es que la respuesta del servidor llega directamente a la pagina donde hicieste la peticion, para evitar una segunda llamada, podrias hacer una llamada ajax en la pagina en la cual tenes que utilizar la respuesta.
osea invertir la secuencia a : pulsar boton -> redireccionar -> peticion ..

Comment: Si es por ahí la cuestión. Encontré una pregunta similar a lo que me pasa: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53593697/forwarding-response-to-another-action-in-struts-and-sending-file-in-response Cuando lo resuelva edito la mia. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

En tu JSP puedes crear una etiqueta script y generar una variable que estará presente cuando se cargue la pagina, algo como

```
<script>
  var data = ${response.datosEnJson};
</script>
```

Luego solo tienes que pasear el JSON (no se si IE7 tiene JSON.parse,podrias usar eval)